# How to add matchers to HttpSecurity spring web secure

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I try to implement spring security, but I have many roles and privileges, then I want to add the roles dynamically to each other resources. Like it:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    super.configure(http);


    //PageRequest p = new PageRequest(0, 1000);

    List<RolePrivilegeConfig> rolePrivilegesConfig=rolePrivilegeConfigService.findAll();

    for (RolePrivilegeConfig rolePrivilegeConfig : rolePrivilegesConfig) {

        http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
        .antMatchers(rolePrivilegeConfig.getResource())
        .access(rolePrivilegeConfig.getRoleName())
        .anyRequest().authenticated();               
    } }
```

I have this error:

> Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method
>   'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't configure antMatchers after
>   anyRequest.

How can I put all matchers and call request after?

Comment: Just call the `httpSecurity.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()` outside of the loop.

Comment: I get: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't configure anyRequest after itself

Answer (score 4):

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    super.configure(http);


    //PageRequest p = new PageRequest(0, 1000);

    List<RolePrivilegeConfig> rolePrivilegesConfig=rolePrivilegeConfigService.findAll();

    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/login").permitAll();

    for (RolePrivilegeConfig rolePrivilegeConfig : rolePrivilegesConfig) {

        http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(rolePrivilegeConfig.getResource())
        .access(rolePrivilegeConfig.getRoleName());
    }

    http.authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works for me, and I didn't have springSecurityFilterChain in web.xml.