# Spring Boot security: Can't configure antMatchers after anyRequest

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I am trying to filter url through `@EnableActiveDirectoryOAuth2ResourceServer`. I have configured the bean of type `ResourceServerConfigurer` according to docs but for some reason I am getting the following error:

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't configure antMatchers after anyRequest`

Code:

```
@EnableActiveDirectoryOAuth2ResourceServer
@EnableWebSecurity
public class OAuthConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ResourceServerConfigurer resourceServerConfigurer() {
        return new ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
                http.csrf()
                        .disable()
                        .requestMatcher(httpGetMethodForPath("/url1"))
                        .requestMatcher(httpGetMethodForPath("/url2"))
                        .requestMatcher(httpGetMethodForPath("/url3"))
                        .authorizeRequests()
                        .anyRequest().access("#oauth2.isClient() and #oauth2.hasScope('myscope')");
            }
        };
    }

    private RequestMatcher httpGetMethodForPath(String URI) {
        return request -> request.getRequestURI().contains(URI) && HttpMethod.GET.name().equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod());
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58420224/how-to-add-matchers-to-httpsecurity-spring-web-secure

Comment: I have same error when use "anyRequest" **after** "authorizeRequests" and "antMatchers".