# Can't configure antMatchers after anyRequest (Multiple antMatcher)

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am trying to configure Spring Security and get this following error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't configure antMatchers after anyRequest

This is my `SecurityConfig` class:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

            auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(encodePWD());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{

        http
            .csrf().disable();
        http
            .httpBasic()
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/rest/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/secure/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .permitAll();

        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll();
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder encodePWD(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

I already tried call `httpSecurityauthorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58420224/how-to-add-matchers-to-httpsecurity-spring-web-secure), 
still didn't work
...any suggestion would be helpfull.

Comment: Not that , `http.httpBasic()
                    .and()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/rest/**")
                    .permitAll()
                    .and()
                    .antMatchers("/secure/**")
                    .hasAnyRole("ADMIN")
                    .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .formLogin().permitAll();` this way.

Comment: thx you....now its work

Comment: May I ask what exactly does "http.csrf().disable()" do? I have seen it in many places. I know the basics of CSRF but why do we need to disable it here? What happens if that line is not there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Authenticated should come last 
httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
                 .cors()
                .and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("xyz").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("abc")
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED);
```

Answer (score 21):

Modify the rule as follows . `.anyRequest().authenticated()` to be used only once .

```
    http
        .httpBasic()
            .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/rest/**").permitAll()
            .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/secure/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .permitAll();
```

Comment: Hmm...why does the "/rest/**" ant matcher need its own authorizeRequests() block, why can't it immediately precede the one for "/secure/**" ?

Comment: solution not work for me:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72698060/reconfig-antmatchers-after-anyrequest-to-update-spring-security-roles-dynamicall

Answer (score 7):

It might help someone for same kind of Exception
Here is my code:-

```
    @Override
      protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        
         http.authorizeRequests()
             .antMatchers("/**")
             .hasAnyRole()
             .and()
             .formLogin();
    }
```

I just removed the call to super class :- super.configure(http); It worked for me. Just remove that line.

Answer (score 0):

```
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    
        http.csrf()
            .disable()
            .cors()
            .disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login", "/user/createUser")
            .permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS)
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and().exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(unautorizeHandler)
            .and().sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

       http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 http
 .httpBasic()
     .and()
 .authorizeRequests()
     .antMatchers("/rest/**").permitAll()
     .and()
 .authorizeRequests()
     .antMatchers("/secure/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN")
     .anyRequest().authenticated()
     .and()
 .formLogin()
     .permitAll();
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).