# Why we get BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I am working on a small spring boot application contains two controllers:-

1)`/www.shopping.com` [just for fun]==This controller can be accessed by any one.

2)`/addtocart`===This controller can be accessed only by person whose role is user.

When ever i am running the application i am getting few exceptions,shown bellow.(I am posting security configuration file as well)

**Security Config file:-**

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConf extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder EncryptPWD() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.httpBasic().and()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/www.shopping.com/**").authenticated()
                .anyRequest()
                .permitAll()
                .and()

                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/addtocart/**")
                .authenticated()
                .anyRequest()
                .hasAnyRole("ROLE_USER")
                .and()

                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()

                .logout()
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .clearAuthentication(true)
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(EncryptPWD());
    }
}
```

**Exceptions:-**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't configure antMatchers after anyRequest
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:655) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:483) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1176) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:311) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:897) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at com.ecommerce.demo.DemoCommerceApplication.main(DemoCommerceApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't configure antMatchers after anyRequest
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:650) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't configure antMatchers after anyRequest
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:76) ~[spring-core-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.AbstractRequestMatcherRegistry.antMatchers(AbstractRequestMatcherRegistry.java:122) ~[spring-security-config-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at com.ecommerce.demo.configuration.SecurityConf.configure(SecurityConf.java:35) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.getHttp(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:231) ~[spring-security-config-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:322) ~[spring-security-config-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:94) ~[spring-security-config-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at com.ecommerce.demo.configuration.SecurityConf$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$eb8f380e.init(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.init(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:370) ~[spring-security-config-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:324) ~[spring-security-config-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:41) ~[spring-security-config-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:104) ~[spring-security-config-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    ... 28 common frames omitted
```

After searching little bit about it,i found this[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60123616/cant-configure-antmatchers-after-anyrequest-multiple-antmatcher/63678020#63678020]stackoverflow question but don't understand why i am getting this exception an how to resolve it.

please someone help me to get out of this rid and please help me to let me why i am getting this exception and how to resolve to when ever needed.

Thanks in advance your words are value for me.

Comment: You have .authenticated().anyRequest() twice. Try to change the first one from .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/www.shopping.com/**").authenticated()
                .anyRequest()
                .permitAll()
                .and()
....to.....authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/www.shopping.com/**")
                .permitAll()
                .and()

Comment: @JonH Thanks it works..Can u please explain why that code not worked.

Comment: `Can't configure antMatchers after anyRequest` there is the error msg... thats why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put the more specific requests first (.antMatchers("/addtocart/**")) before the more general requests (.anyRequest()).