# Can't configure antMatchers after anyRequest? how to resolve

Tags: java, security

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't configure antMatchers after anyRequest
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:650) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
... 22 common frames omitted
```

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't configure antMatchers after anyRequest

```
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Security
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String[] STATIC_RESOURCES = {
            "/api/test-api"
    };

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(STATIC_RESOURCES).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
        // @formatter:on
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60150046/175554 helps ?